# Having problems with grabbing image dimensions with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a hard time picking up how to grab the dimensions of an element with jQuery. Here is my sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var width = $("#image_1").width();
        var height = $("#image_1").height();
        document.write(width);
        document.write(height);
    });
```

Now of course I have an image with an id of #image_1. What happens when I try to run it is that it outputs two zeros. Not null twice, or undefined twice.

Thanks for the help from a javascript newb.

Comment: In addition, the image does not appear in the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo() {
            var image = document.getElementById("the_image");
            alert(image.offsetWidth);
            alert(image.offsetHeight);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="foo();">
    <img src="img.png" id="the_image">
</body>
```

This works as long as the image is not set to `display: none;` Using `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` also has the advantage of not requiring jQuery, at all.

Comment: That returns undefined for both. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample? It works for me (as shown in my edit above).

Comment: I did something like the edit and it did work. I was messing around with something I have to do at work tomorrow. Basically I have a gallery that has a frame of 400x300, and most of the images are 395x295. But with some are smaller, and I want to center the small ones. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm trying to accept your answer and it just shows a red box with the filename of the checkmark.....weird.

Comment: I cannot access offsetWidth if the image has not loaded. The comment by Josh Stodola below addresses the problem better. Like he said, either use `$(window).load(function() {` or `$('#the_image').load(function() {`.

Answer (score 8):

Even though you've already chosen an answer, I am typing this one so you understand why your prior code did not work.

jQuery's document.ready function fires before images are loaded.  Use window.load instead...

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var width = $("#image_1").width();
  var height = $("#image_1").height();
  document.write(width);
  document.write(height);
});
```

For what it's worth, I think it is better to use jQuery for this task because of the inherent cross-browser functionality.

Comment: Agreed, I have since used something like that on jQuery as it does work better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may get `0` for the width and height if the image is not visible. (That's what just happened to me.)

**Updated**: You can confirm that the image is added to the DOM by checking the length property of the jQuery object:

```
var inDOM = ($('#image_1').length > 0);
```

Comment: It is visible, but jquery is basically choking and not showing the image. I was thinking along those lines. How can I tell if its actually inserted inside the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this was a typo in your question, but is the ID of your image really "#image_1"?  For your code to work, it should be just "image_1".  The "#" is only used in the jquery selector to specify that the text following it is an ID.